# How to create table in dialogflow-fulfillment

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

In actions-on-google we can add table like :

```
const {dialogflow, Table} = require('actions-on-google');
const request = require('request');
const conv = new DialogflowConversation(request);
conv.ask('This is a simple table example.');
conv.ask(new Table({
     dividers: true,
    columns: ['header 1', 'header 2', 'header 3'],
     rows: [
         ['row 1 item 1', 'row 1 item 2', 'row 1 item 3'],
         ['row 2 item 1', 'row 2 item 2', 'row 2 item 3'],
     ],
}));
```

How to create the table using dialogflow-fulfillment ??

Actually in my case, I am using dialogflow-fulfillment.
ANd I want to use like :

```
agent.add(new Table({
     dividers: true,
     columns: ['header 1', 'header 2', 'header 3'],
     rows: [
       ['row 1 item 1', 'row 1 item 2', 'row 1 item 3'],
       ['row 2 item 1', 'row 2 item 2', 'row 2 item 3'],
     ],
 }));
```

Can I do it like this using dialogflow-fulfillment?

Answer (score 2):

From the source code of library, it doesn't seem that `Table` is still provided in that.

By looking at the [source](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs) I can say it is providing

- Text
- Cards
- Images
- Suggestion Chips (Quick Replies)

Even if we look at src folder it is not having anything related to `Table`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, yes. It depends on exactly where you expect the table to work.

There is no table definition for Dialogflow integrations in general. So you can't create a table that will work on the Facebook integration.

However, if you want to create a table for Actions on Google, you can do this. Instead of trying to add it to your `agent` object, you can get a `conv` object using `agent.getConv()` and use this to add a table with `conv.add()`.

I haven't tested this, but it might be something like this:

```
const { WebhookClient } = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const { Table } = require('actions-on-google');

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });

  function assistantTableHandler(agent) {
    let conv = agent.conv(); // Get Actions on Google library conversation object
    conv.ask('Please choose an item:'); // Use Actions on Google library to add responses
    conv.ask(new Table({
     dividers: true,
     columns: ['header 1', 'header 2', 'header 3'],
     rows: [
       ['row 1 item 1', 'row 1 item 2', 'row 1 item 3'],
       ['row 2 item 1', 'row 2 item 2', 'row 2 item 3'],
     ],
    }));
  };

// Add handler registration, etc

}
```

You can [see a more complete example](https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-actions-library-nodejs) of how to use Actions on Google object using the dialogflow-fulfillment library.

Comment: is that possible to use table and corousel on dialogflow embeded on web ??

Comment: No. These response types are only available for the Google Assistant.