# How to add Table Card in Dialogflow Fulfillment?

Tags: c#, dialogflow-es

I've been working on my Dialogflow Fulfillment in my Webhook / Web API and I'm now looking at the Fulfillment Messages part of the response. I've realized it has to be a list of `GoogleCloudDialogflowV2IntentMessage`.

Looking at the metadata of that class; I see this:

[image: GoogleCloudDialogflowV2IntentMessageMeta]

It seems to support all these types of responses:

- Basic Card
- Card
- Carousel Select
- Image
- Link Out Suggestion
- List Select
- Payload
- Quick Replies
- Simple Responses
- Suggestions
- Text

When I was working in the Dialogflow Console; if I clicked on 'Add Response' under the 'Google Assistant' responses; there were options that are not directly in this `GoogleCloudDialogflowV2IntentMessage` class. The option I'm interested in is: 'Table Card'.

How can I make my API return a 'Table Card' as a response?

Can I somehow pass details of a 'Table Card' in the 'Payload' property?

Am I misunderstanding something somewhere along the lines?

Help / Advice appreciated.

Comment: Refer [How to create table in dialogflow-fulfillment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56964982/how-to-create-table-in-dialogflow-fulfillment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TableCard is available for the Google Assistant only. It is not available for other integration types. Using it puts the information in the platform-specific `Payload` field.

You can put whatever you want in the `Payload` field - but it won't do you any good unless the platform that is receiving it knows what to do with it.

Comment: I've tried adding my table card object into the payload field in a few different ways, but when I test it in the Google Assistant simulator; it doesn't work. It doesn't display. How can I find out in what format or in what way it should be added to the payload field; so the Google Assistant can interpret it correctly?

Comment: I was able to find a solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57755848/how-to-display-a-table-card-from-dialogflow-webhook-in-google-assistant/57760162#57760162