# How to display a Table Card from Dialogflow Webhook in Google Assistant

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I've setup a ASP.NET MVC 4 Web API to handle dialogflow fulfillment. My goal is to integrate with Google Assistant and display a Table Card as a response. I'm testing through the Google Actions Console Simulator.

I've added the Table Card details in the `GoogleCloudDialogflowV2IntentMessage` `Payload` field, based on what I've found out here:

[How to add Table Card in Dialogflow Fulfillment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57599794/how-to-add-table-card-in-dialogflow-fulfillment)

The Fulfillment Response from my API Webhook ends up looking something like this:

```
{
  "followupEventInput": {
    "languageCode": null,
    "name": null,
    "parameters": null,
    "ETag": null
  },
  "fulfillmentMessages": [
    {
      "basicCard": null,
      "card": null,
      "carouselSelect": null,
      "image": null,
      "linkOutSuggestion": null,
      "listSelect": null,
      "payload": {
        "google": {
          "expectUserResponse": false,
          "richResponse": {
            "items": [
              {
                "simpleResponse": {
                  "textToSpeech": "Simple Response TEST",
                  "ssml": "Simple Response TEST SSML",
                  "displayText": "Simple Response TEST DISPLAY"
                }
              },
              {
                "tableCard": {
                  "title": "Title",
                  "subtitle": "Subtitle",
                  "image": {
                    "url": "https://www.google.org/static/logo_googledotorg.svg",
                    "accessibilityText": "Image Accessibility Text TEST"
                  },
                  "columnProperties": [
                    {
                      "header": "BanksID",
                      "horizontalAlignment": "LEADING"
                    },
                    {
                      "header": "Name",
                      "horizontalAlignment": "LEADING"
                    }
                  ],
                  "rows": [
                    {
                      "cells": [
                        {
                          "text": "3"
                        },
                        {
                          "text": "Bank 1 TEST"
                        }
                      ],
                      "dividerAfter": false
                    }
                  ],
                  "buttons": [
                    {
                      "title": "Weblink Title",
                      "openUrlAction": {
                        "url": "https://www.google.org",
                        "urlTypeHint": "URL_TYPE_HINT_UNSPECIFIED"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "platform": null,
      "quickReplies": null,
      "simpleResponses": {
        "simpleResponses": [
          {
            "displayText": "Simple Response DISPLAY TEST",
            "ssml": "Simple Response TEST SSML",
            "textToSpeech": "Simple Response TEST",
            "ETag": null
          }
        ],
        "ETag": null
      },
      "suggestions": null,
      "text": null,
      "ETag": null
    }
  ],
  "fulfillmentText": "TEST successful.",
  "outputContexts": [
    {
      "lifespanCount": 5,
      "name": "banks",
      "parameters": {
        "TForView": "rra",
        "DBVerb": "rra",
        "TForView.original": "",
        "DBVerb.original": ""
      },
      "ETag": null
    }
  ],
  "payload": null,
  "source": null,
  "ETag": null
}
```

Problem is I'm not seeing the Table Card in the simulator. The format of my JSON response is probably not correct, so Google Assistant can't interpret it correctly, but I don't know how to change it. I don't know what the correct format is. Or perhaps I'm missing something else.

How can I display a Table Card in Google Assistant from a Webhook Response?

Any help / other ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at the Dialogflow Console > DIAGNOSTIC INFO > FULFILLMENT STATUS.

I found out that in the `GoogleCloudDialogflowV2IntentMessage` I'm setting both the `SimpleResponses` field and the `Payload` field; and Google Assistant didn't quite like that. So I've set the `SimpleResponses` field to `null` and then got the desired display response on the Google Actions Simulator.

The `SimpleResponses` is already added into the `Payload` field and Google Assistant didn't have trouble with that, just the fact that both `Payload` and `SimpleResponses` were set.